# removing "none" result from the function which prints the prime number

Tags: python

i wanna write a function that if the number is prime the function gives it as a result,but for non prime numbers i get a None,here is my code:

```
def isprime(n):

    a=0
    if n==1:
        a=1
    if n==2:
        a=1
    for i in range(2,n):

        if n%i==0:
            a=0
            break
        else:
            a=1
            break
    if a==1:
        return n
    if a==0:
        return


print(isprime(68))
```

the result for 68 is None

Comment: `if a==0: return 'not a prime'` You can do something like that the problem is that you're trying to print out something but you're not returning anything, just returning control back to the calling function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to print `None` when you get that returned from your function, you need to change the printing code, rather than the function's code. Use something like:

```
p = isprime(x)
if p is not None:
    print(p)
```

But your `isprime` function isn't actually working properly anyway. It will always return `None` for any value other than 2 or 3.

This is because the `for` loop will run only a single iteration, because you always hit a `break` statement in the `if` or `else` block it contains. You don't want to `break` if the number you tested is not a divisor. In fact, you don't need to do anything in that case.

Just use:

```
for i in range(2,n):
    if n%i==0:
        a=0
        break
```

with no `else` block.

Note that you could simplify it a bit by using a `return` in the `if` block rather than setting a flag variable (which should really be given a more meaningful name than `a` if you do intend to keep it).

Here's a streamlined version of the same algorithm. I've added a few improvements, such as stopping the range after `int(sqrt(n))`, and iterating only on odd values (since 2 is handled by a special case at the beginning). I'm also explicitly naming `None` as the return value, to make it clear that it is intentional to return that value when `n` is a composite (a bare `return` makes it seem like the `None` is supposed to be ignored):

```
def isprime(n):    
    if n==1:
        return None
    if n==2:
        return 2
    for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2):
        if n%i==0:
            return None
    return n
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of not a prime number (a=0) you return nothing:

```
if a==0:
    return
```

and if you print the value of a function which returns nothing, it prints `None`.

To solve this, return a number, or in this case a boolean would be more logical. So instead of setting `a=0` or `a=1` you can use `a=False` and `a=True`. Then you can do `return a`.

Comment: even if i remove that, i still get None

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili you need to return something there, if you don't return anything then when the variable a is equal to zero it will implicitly return to the calling function and won't have anything to print out.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually good practice in methods that require you to print something out to have a "base-case" because you should never get a none-type because you will always be returning something back to the print/calling function.

```
a=0
if n==1:
    a=1
if n==2:

    a=1
for i in range(2,n):
    if n%i==0:
        a=0
        break

    else:
        a=1
        break

if a==1:
    return n

# By having a base case return statement we will
#    never print out a none type, even upon error.
return (n + 'is not prime')
```